# Removing points in a vector based on another

Tags: r

I've two vectors with data x and y. Let's say the first one is the distance and the second the temperature.

How can I remove from both x and y all points which distance is lower a constant distance 'd' between two consecutive points ( xi - xi-1 )

```
x = (1,2,3,8,12)
y = (10,12,11,9,12)
```

remove points with a distance smaller than 5

```
x  = 1, 2(out as 2-1 <5), 3 (out as 3-1 <5), 8, 12 (fine as last even thoug 12-8<5)
x  = (1,8,12)
y  = (10,9,12)
```

Comment: If your two vectors contain information about the same observations, you should consider storing them in a `data.frame`. Then any filtering operation you do (either using base `R` or a function from an external library such as `filter` from`dplyr`) will be done row wise.

Comment: @imo, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea assuming that your first and last elements are never removed,

```
v1 <- setNames(x, y)[c(TRUE, (diff(x) >= 5)[-(length(x)-1)], TRUE)]
#10  9 12 
# 1  8 12 

#To make it a bit more clear on how the named vector is structured (still a vector)

names(v1)
#[1] "10" "9"  "12"    <- Note: I get 9 whereas you get 11

unname(v1)
#[1]  1  8 12
```

Or you can make it a function,

```
rm_elements <- function(x, y, n){
  v1 <- setNames(x, y)[c(TRUE, (diff(x) >= n)[-(length(x)-1)], TRUE)]
  return(list(x = unname(v1), y = as.numeric(names(v1))))
}

rm_elements(x, y, 5)
#$x
#[1]  1  8 12

#$y
#[1] 10  9 12
```

**EDIT**: To accomodate your comment for when you have them in a data frame, then we can alter the function a bit to accept a data frame (no matter how you name the variables), and return a subset of that data frame, i.e.

```
rm_elements <- function(df, n){
  v1 <- df[c(TRUE, (diff(df[[1]]) >= n)[-(nrow(df)-1)], TRUE),]
  return(v1)
}

#Make a data frame from the vectors,
d1 <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

 rm_elements(d1, 5)
```

which gives,

> ```
>    x  y
> 1  1 10
> 4  8  9
> 5 12 12
> ```

Comment: You mean you want it to return a data frame rather than a list?

Comment: if I bind x and y with data.frame(  x, y ) instead of setNames

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look